# How can LINQ return the same result only one time c#

Tags: linq

I have a List of dates, where I only need the same result one time from the list.

```
var myYear =
    from a in aktiekursListe
    join d in datoListe on a.IdDato equals d.Id
    orderby d.DateTime descending
    select new { d.DateTime.Year };

  foreach (var item in myYear)
  {
    label_Info.Content += " Year: " + item.Year.ToString();
  }
```

The result from the label:
Year: 2013 Year: 2013 Year: 2013 ect.

The result I need:
Year: 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
foreach (var item in myYear.Distinct())
{
  label_Info.Content += " Year: " + item.Year.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Nice and easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pick the first one?

```
var myYear =
    from a in aktiekursListe
    join d in datoListe on a.IdDato equals d.Id
    orderby d.DateTime descending
    select new { d.DateTime.Year };
label_Info.Content += " Year: " + myYear.First().Year.ToString();
```

Comment: I need year: 2013, 2012,2011 ect.